# Delete a Folder from Google Drive File Sync with CMD?

Tags: command-line, powershell, google-drive

I am looking to delete a folder from Google Drive (Google adds it as G:\ on my machine) using CMD or PowerShell. I have tried `rd /q /s <<filePath>>` and `Remove-Item -Force <<filePath>>`.

However, no matter what I try, both CMD and PowerShell tell me that the folder is in use and cannot be deleted. However, if I go to Explorer and delete the folder from there, there is no problem, and Drive Sync happily notifies me that the folder was deleted, leaving me to believe it’s Google Drive itself causing this.

Is there a way I can delete a Google Drive folder from CMD/PowerShell?

Comment: Google has an extension loaded into Explorer that allows "normal" Explorer commands to translate into the appropriate Google Drive commands. Unless Google offers similar integration for the command interpreter or PowerShell, you are out of luck.

Comment: I don't have Google drive, but if it responds to Explorer commands, this should be easiy doable. So please clarify: It appears as a drive under **This PC**, it's not rooted in the the Desktop/Navigaiton pane, right? Do you delete it via the context menu? If so, what's the command?